# Cannot setup elastic search in Windows 8.1

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup elastic search on my PC (Windows 8.1)
What I did so far:
- Download ES 1.7.1 from here: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch
- Install JAVA 1.8.0 and set JAVA_HOME variable
- Run the elasticsearch.bat

I got status of "200" at first but now when i try to access http://localhost:9200 or try to execute the elasticsearch.bat i am getting an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've put the elasticsearch folder in `C:` drive. Most probably it is your system drive and elasticsearch does not have permission to create files in this drive. Hence you see those exceptions. I would recommend putting the elasticsearch folder in a non-system drive and executing from there.